# Include Key AND salt for signing JWT in NestJS

Tags: phoenix-framework, nestjs, jwt

I have a component written with the Phoenix-Framework (it's elixir under the hood),
which I am re-writing in NestJS.

JWTs are used as a mean of authentication.
There is a part where after a user registers, an e-mail containing an confirmation link is send.
The way Phoenix signs the JWT Token is by using the  [sign](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Token.html#sign/4) Method.

It has the following signature: `sign(context, salt, data, opts \\ [])`

Here's the thing:
Context is where Elixir finds the *secret key base*, this can be seen as a symmetric key for the signing process.  But, you also pass another "secret", which is the *salt*.

Now, in NestJS, all I have found so far is the [jwt utility nest module](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt) which uses the [json-webtoken node module](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback).

In there, all you can do is the following:  `jwt.sign(payload, secretOrPrivateKey, [options, callback])`

Under options, there is no "salt" option.

My main question: How do I include a salt in here?
My other side-questions:
1) If I don't use basic SHA-256, but HMAC-SHA or whats it called, do I even need a salt?
2) The `sign` method from nestjs/jwt only uses 1 parameter:

```
jwtService.sign(payload: string | Object | Buffer, options?: SignOptions): string
```

> The sign method is an implementation of jsonwebtoken .sign().

How do I even pass the secret-key there? Or is it automatically used after I configured it at the beginning:

```
JwtModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    secret: configService.getString('SECRET'),
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer you how to include salt in this particular case, but as far as I know, it is quite common to only use a secret for the signing of the header and payload.

The secret is automatically used from the configuration of the JwtModule by using the sing() function.